# Multiple instance of angular 4 directive called from a component mesed up the input values

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a component in angular 4 that is called three times. In template metadata I have a div with a directive with some bindings like this.

```
@import {gServ} from '../gServ.service';

@Component: ({
   selector: 'sr-comp',
   template: `<div gDirective [cOptions]="dataChart">`
})

export class SGComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('report') public report: IReportInstance;
    cOptions:any;

    constructor(private gServ: gServ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.cOptions = {};
        this.cOptions = this.gServ.objectMerge(this.gServ.defaultOpt, this.report.opt);

        //this.report.opt is binded to a component when is instantiated.
        //this.gServ.objectMerge is a function that merge the two objects
    }
}
```

this.cOptions change for every instance of the component, then in the directive I have this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[gDirective]'
})
export class SGDirective implements OnInit {
  public _element: any;
  @Input() public cOptions: string;

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
    this._element = this.element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.cOptions);
  }
}
```

The problem is that `console.log(this.cOptions);` always print the same object, even when component set `cOptions` with diferent values in `ngOnInit` method of the compnent.

Do you have some idea what is wrong?

Comment: I have the simillar problem.

Comment: Did you try `console.log` directly the result of the service, in your component `ngOnInit`. `this.cOptions = this.gServ.objectMerge(...); console.log(this.cOptions);`

Answer (score 3):

Your component property binding `[cOptions]="dataChart"` doesn't look good, reason being your `dataChart` is not even defined. it should be like `[DIRECTIVE_PROPERTY]="COMPONENT_PROPERTY"` and your `COMPONENT_PROPERTY` is not even defined in `SGComponent` component class.

Your component class should be something like this:

```
@import {gServ} from '../gServ.service';

@Component: ({
   selector: 'sr-comp',
   template: `<div gDirective [cOptions]="Options">`
})

export class SGComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('report') public report: IReportInstance;
    Options:any;

    constructor(private gServ: gServ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.Options = {};
        this.Options = this.gServ.objectMerge(this.gServ.defaultOpt, this.report.opt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ashwani points out a valid problem with your code.  The way your template is wiring things up, nothing will ever be passed to the `SGDirective` input.

Another potential problem you could be running into has to do with the `gServ` code.  If `gServ` is a singleton (which is probably the case) and it is returning the same object to each of the `SGComponent`s, then all the `SGDirective`s will have the same value.  A simple way to test this is to put `{{Options | json}}` in the `SGComponent` template.

To create a new instance of the `gServ` service for each `SGComponent` you can add a `providers` array to the `@Component` metadata.  It would look like this:

```
import {gServ} from '../gServ.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'sr-comp',
   template: `{{Options | json}}<div gDirective [cOptions]="Options"></div>`
   providers: [gServ],
})

export class SGComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('report') public report: IReportInstance;
    Options:any;

    constructor(private gServ: gServ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.Options = this.gServ.objectMerge(this.gServ.defaultOpt, this.report.opt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably the same return/value at `this.gServ.objectMerge)` (you can test it wihtout calling the service, and passing each one one different objet make by you)

```js
@import {gServ} from '../gServ.service';

@Component: ({
   selector: 'sr-comp',
   template: `<div gDirective [cOptions]="dataChart">`
})

export class SGComponent implements OnInit {
    //@Input('report') public report: IReportInstance;
    cOptions:any;

    constructor(private gServ: gServ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.cOptions = {nicolas: 'nicolas1'}; //change this in the next component that use the directive

    }
}
```

If that is the case, your problem is that gServ is provide at the same rootComponent. with angular, service provider at the same rootComponent are singleton.

And use the same type in your directive and your component!!